# How many passes of a table are done with UNION ALL?

Tags: union

I am trying to run a single query that will make a single pass through a table, and was wondering if by using `UNION ALL` to make counts of total row unioned with counts of unique rows so I would be unioning a query with from the same table.

Would this operation require a double passing of the table?

Comment: Check the execution plan. And please add the tag (`postgresql`, `oracle`, ...) for your DBMS

Comment: that query does not make sense it you don't tell us what dbms your are using and what query you are posing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each query in UNION ALL is executed separately, union only "merges" the result sets so if each query needs to read entire table, it will be done twice. You can check that with [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) in MySQL or similar commands in other RDBMS.

One usage for UNION (ALL) is actually optimizing queries with OR conditions, where separate queries can use indexes better than one "bigger" query.

In your case it seems you might still do it with only one query. Just quessing here from what you wrote but did you consider using

```
SELECT count(col) AS totalCount, count(distinct col) AS uniqueCount FROM ...
```

?

Or [WITH ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modiffier for GROUP BY? (It is MySQL - other RDBMS will probably have something similar)

Comment: Well I am reporting three different counts for each of the total data and distinct data, so i need to include a where clause somewhere, which seems akin to a pivot table.  I also thought of creating an two different aliases for the same table instead of using the union all.  would this be a more efficient approach with only one pass of the table?

Comment: Two aliases would mean joining the table to itself - that might multiply the row count to scan. Use EXPLAIN to see what is happening and if you want something more specific, add your query, the explain results and CREATE TABLE statements to your question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @jkavalik's solution:

```
SELECT count(col) AS totalCount
     , count(distinct col) AS uniqueCount 
FROM ...
```

You can use case:

```
SELECT count(col) AS totalCount
     , count(distinct col) AS uniqueCount 
     , count( case when ... then 1 end ) as conditional_count
FROM ...
```

Not sure this is what you are after but you mention a where clause in one of your comments, and this might be what you wish for.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I need, but I need the distinct clause inside the case is that possible?

Comment: @user11235813 Edit your question and describe what exactly your query is doing. People do not have a crystal ball to answer a question that hasn't been asked.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to combine distinct and case, but it would help if you add some sample data and the expected output to your question. As @ybercube points out, it is very difficult to give any specific advise without knowing what it is you want.